# Correct Way of Updating a Perl Global Variable

Tags: perl, scope, global-variables

I have the following global in variable in file_1.pl, in package main:

```
package main;

my $var = -1;
```

If I need to update this variable from another perl file, what is the way of doing it? I tried:

```
$main::var = 1
```

But it did not work.

What is the correct way of doing it?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to declare the variable with `our` otherwise it would be considered as *lexical* variable so change it like

```
our $var = -1;
```

Comment: I'm just guessing that the downvote comes from that the question uses the words "correct way", you just showed him how globals are *done* in Perl, when the FAQ-ish "correct answer" is to 1) use lexicals whenever possible, 2) check and see if a lexical *can* fit your purpose, 3) use package methods, like in Brian's answer below, 4) if you cannot do other, set them in as *local* a scope as possible. `{ local $PackageVar = -1; do_something_with_PackageVar(); } # out here $PackageVar is unset.`

Comment: Also perhaps, from the terminology. "Local variable" implies something to do with the "local" function. Lexical variables have nothing to do with "local".

Comment: @Axeman,@davorg: ok that might be the reason, I should used the right terminology i.e, _lexical_ variable instead of _local_ variable. Thanks

Comment: `our` creates a lexical alias to a global variable.

Answer (score 8):

The `my` makes a lexical variable. It's scoped to it's block, or, if not in a block, to the file. They can't be seen outside of their scope.

You could create a global variable, as other answers have shown:

```
our $var;
```

However, a better way is to give other parts of the code an interface to updating the lexical version:

```
my $private;

sub set_private { $private = shift }
```

However, if you are going to do that, you might as well have an interface for getting the value too. Now that variable only needs to be in the same scope as the subroutines that use it, so you can hide it from the rest of the file:

```
{
my $private;
sub set_private { $private = shift }

sub get_private { $private }
}
```

Now you're just one step away from an object (in this case, a singleton):

```
use v5.12;

package Foo {
    my $private;
    sub new { bless \$private, shift }
    sub set { my $self = shift; $$self = shift; }

    sub get { my $self = shift; $$self; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper function.

In main file

```
our $var;
sub updateGlobal {
   $var = shift;
}
```

In the other file just call a function

```
updateGlobal(1);
```